# Bash for loop file listing caching

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash `for` loop iterating over files in a directory. If I add files into the directory after the script has began running, will it also process these files (assuming they are alphabetically after the current file), or does it fetch the list of files upon initial execution and only process the files that were already in the directory when execution began?

Comment: If the process is already running, it will not look at the new files that are added after the process started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `for` iterates to whatever list is specified (in other words, to what `*` or whatever you specify expands) at the time when its execution starts.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the list is generated only once (when that particular line of code gets interpreted) and bash as such does not provide a mechanism which would update the currently executing list, although this would not be a feature of bash but rather the command itself, which reads the directory structure (i.e. ls).

for built-in is a collection consumer and not a provider hence the focus here should be on the list provider instead.